# Fastest way to understand business logic in a new project

Tags: documentation, use-case, business-logic

I would like to know the fastest/best way to learn the business logic in a new project.

Most projects have been running for years, some of them are poorly documented, but you still need to know how to work with them. What is the best way to do this? (Use Case Diagram / support from colleagues / code analysis etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with verbose logging is that you may be overloaded with details that do not help, and even if you have the right details, you may misunderstand the big picture.

Moreover, if projects run for years, and are poorly documented, chances are the little available documentation is already obsolete.  And chances are, the team did not invest heavily in logging either.

Reverse engineering the code is another approach,  but where to start if there are millions of lines of code in the legacy system?  Some things can be easily read in code, but many more complex, emergent behavior comes from the interactions between many classes, and this kind of knowledge is the most difficult to extract.

So here is the way to go:

1. Talk to colleagues. The best approach to move knowledge from one brain to another is direct conversation. It works much better than any formal diagram or any documentation.  Unfortunately this is not always possible (e.g. team left)
2. If 1 is not possible,  understand the business user's point of view. May be there is a user manual? Maybe some colleagues of the user-support?  if none of those are possible, the ultimate way is to spend some time in the day of the user's life. You will not understand how the system works, but at least you'll get a quick intro in what the system is supposed to do, what matters to the users,  and maybe some business rules.
3. Check for automated test cases. In fact, such test cases are a hidden and up-to date documentation resource.
4. Check for non-automated test cases, in particular use acceptance tests, and integration tests.  If these are not automated,  there are chances that they are already obsolete.  But it's better than nothing.
5. Reverse engineer the code. Identify the main classes and how they interact.  And yes, some simplified class diagrams will help you to understand how classes are related (no need to document properties and methods: these can be found back in the code).  And some sequence diagram will help you to get a picture of the more complex interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Run server, log verbose everywhere. Follow code flow and dig in.